# AWS service can't start task, but starting task manually works

Tags: amazon-web-services, service, connection, task, amazon-ecs

Until now I had a backend running single tasks. I now want to switch to services starting my tasks. For two of the tasks I need direct access to them so I tried using ServiceConnect.

When I run this task standalone it starts. When I start a service without ServiceConnect with the same task inside it also starts. When I enable ServiceConnect I get this error message inside of the 'Deployments and events' tab in the service:

```
service (...) was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. 
The closest matching container-instance (...) is missing an attribute required by your task. 
For more information, see the Troubleshooting section of the Amazon ECS Developer Guide.
```

When I check the attributes of all free containers with:
`ecs-cli check-attributes --task-def some-task-definition --container-instances ... --cluster some-cluster`
I just get:

```
Container Instance  Missing Attributes
heyvie-backend-dev  None
```

My task definition looks like that:

```
{
  "family": "some-task-definition",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::...:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::...:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "1024",
  "memory": "982",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "...",
      "image": "...",
      "essential": true,
      "healthCheck": {
        "command": ["..."],
        "startPeriod": 20,
        "retries": 3
      },
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "name": "somePortName",
          "containerPort": 4321
        }
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "...",
          "containerPath": "..."
        }
      ],
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "...",
          "awslogs-region": "eu-...",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "..."
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "...",
      "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
        "fileSystemId": "...",
        "rootDirectory": "/",
        "transitEncryption": "ENABLED"
      }
    }
  ],
  "requiresCompatibilities": ["EC2"]
}
```

My service definition looks like that:

```
{
  "cluster": "some-cluster",
  "serviceName": "...",
  "taskDefinition": "some-task-definition",
  "desiredCount": 1,
  "launchType": "EC2",
  "deploymentConfiguration": {
    "maximumPercent": 100,
    "minimumHealthyPercent": 0
  },
  "placementConstraints": [
    {
      "type": "distinctInstance"
    }
  ],
  "networkConfiguration": {
    "awsvpcConfiguration": {
      "subnets": [
        ...
      ],
      "securityGroups": ["..."],
      "assignPublicIp": "DISABLED"
    }
  },
  "serviceConnectConfiguration": {
    "enabled": true,
    "namespace": "someNamespace",
    "services": [
      {
        "portName": "somePortName",
        "clientAliases": [
          {
            "port": 4321
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "schedulingStrategy": "REPLICA",
  "enableECSManagedTags": true,
  "propagateTags": "SERVICE"
}
```

I also added this to the user data of my launch template:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<'EOF' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
ECS_ENABLE_TASK_IAM_ROLE=true
ECS_CLUSTER=some-cluster
EOF
```

Did anyone experience something similiar or does know what could cause that issue?

Answer (score 1):

I used ServiceDiscovery, I think, it's the easiest way to replace a dynamic ip address of a task in a service (on every restart the ip address changes and that's probably what you're trying to avoid?).

With ServiceDiscovery you are creating a new DNS record and instead of `ip-address:port` you can just use `serviceNameOfNamespace.namespace.` to connect to a task. ServiceDiscovery worked without any problem on an existing task.

Hope that helps, I don't really know if there are any benefits for ServiceConnect except for higher connection counts and retry functionalities, so if anybody knows more about differences between those I'm happy to learn.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into ServiceDiscovery again, I didn't like the fact that it brings additional cost for route 53 but that was just my fast first impression. The connection count is not important, our backend is still pretty small and we already have retry functionality in our services.